# Using response from Azure cli (json) in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

All I want to do is to see if my IP is already whitelisted for the company key vault and if not then add it.

The response of `az keyvault network-rule list` isn't a string (if it was then I could just `-match` but it's something else and I can't figure out any way to use it in PowerShell.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
[string] $ip = (Invoke-WebRequest -uri "http://icanhazip.com/" -UseBasicParsing).Content

[bool] $loggedIn = ((((az account show) -match "tenantId").Count) -gt 0)

if( $b -eq $False ) {
    az login
}

[bool] $alreadyAdded = (((az keyvault network-rule list --name xxx) -match "$ip".Replace(".", "\.")).Count -gt 0)
# The command returns JSON which can't be -match ed and is useless after applying ConvertFrom-Json

if( $alreadyAdded -eq $False ) {
    echo "Adding IP $ip."
    az keyvault network-rule add --name xxx --ip-address "$ip"
    # It would be good to remove old IPs.
}
else {
    echo "Adress $ip is already added."
}
```

This seems to be a way to get the list of current IPs, but it seems to be impossible to test in PowerShell whether this list contains `$ip`. Or is there a way?

```
> az keyvault network-rule list --name xxx --query "ipRules" | ConvertFrom-Json 

value             
-----             
xxx.133.237.168/32 
xxx.39.179.102/32  
xxx.8.15.24/32     
xxx.40.138.215/32  
xxx.42.242.94/32   
xxx.36.228.115/32  
xxx.101.245.58/32  
xxx.27.46.155/32   
xxx.103.237.247/32 
xxx.28.15.154/32   
xxx.132.244.148/32 
xxx.132.247.90/32  
xxx.249.181.76/32 
xxx.205.197.115/32
```

Comment: As an aside: `(Invoke-WebRequest -uri "http://icanhazip.com/" -UseBasicParsing).Content` can be simplified to (use [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod)): `Invoke-RestMethod -uri http://icanhazip.com/`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you trim any whitespace from the output from the IP query:

```
$ip = $ip.Trim()
```

Then use the `Where-Object` command to filter on the `value` property of each resulting object:

```
$MatchingIP = az keyvault network-rule list --name xxx --query "ipRules" | ConvertFrom-Json |Where-Object value -like "$ip/32"

if($MatchingIP){
    # Found a /32 entry for $ip
}
```